# How to get column values from datatable to textbox?

Tags: c#

I want to get all the values in the column..
here is my code..

```
private void btnLeftArrow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) { con.Close(); }
        con.Open();
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Group_Name", con);
        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (obj != null)
            txtGroupName.Text = obj.ToString();
        con.Close();
}
```

it is displaying only first value..but I want to get other values for every click of button..
My table has only one column

Comment: Check this link: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
while(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
txtGroupName.Text=dt.Rows[0]["column_name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand why this answer selected. This doesn't even explain how to set `dt` from the results of your `SqlCommand`.

Answer (score 3):

[`ExecuteScalar` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the first column of the first row. All other columns or rows are ignored.

If you want to return all values in column, you need to use [`SqlDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) and [`ExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with *while statement* at least. [`SqlDataReader.Read` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads your reader *rows by rows* by the way.

For example;

```
...
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Group_Name", con);
using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(reader.Read())
   {
      string firstcolumn = reader[0].ToString(); // It is zero-indexed.
   }
}
```

But looks like you want to add these values to your `TextBox`, you can add them with a white space in a `List<T>`, then you can use them for your `TextBox` like (I assume your values are `string`);

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
...
...
while(reader.Read())
{
   list.Add(reader[0].ToString());
}
TextBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", list.ToArray());
```

If you use .NET 4 or higher, you don't need to use `.ToArray()` because [there is an overload of `String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes an `IEnumerable<string>`

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteScalr` returns a single value where as `ExecuteReader` returns collection of rows.
so if you want all the results use `ExecuteReader`